# There was a problem with the requested skill's response using template, Alexa skill using template directive

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have an issue with alexa skill in node.

i'm making an skill that connect with db via HTTS.response

everything works fine until I want to show the results in a template.

this its the response.

```
{
"outputSpeech": {
    "type": "PlainText",
    "text": "That's sound good. Your search is Property Type: residential -  City:Petersburg - Zip Code:33715 - Bedrooms:2 - Price: $100000"
},
"directives": [
    {
        "type": "Display.RenderTemplate",
        "template": {
            "type": "ListTemplate2",
            "token": "ShowHomeView",
            "backButton": "hidden",
            "backgroundImage": {
                "contentDescription": "",
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "url": "https://s3.amazonaws_com/ask-samples-resources/berryImages/main_blur2.png"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "title": "Search Results",
            "listItems": [
                {
                    "token": 1,
                    "image": "https://mydomain/images/fine_arts-1550.jpg",
                    "textContent": "This is my list item 1"
                },
                {
                    "token": 2,
                    "image": "https://mydomain/images/fine_arts-1550.jpg",
                    "textContent": "This is my list item 2"
                },
                {
                    "token": 3,
                    "image": "https://mydomain/images/fine_arts-1550.jpg",
                    "textContent": "This is my list item 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Hint",
        "hint": {
            "type": "PlainText",
            "text": " select number two. "
        }
    }
],
"shouldEndSession": false
```

}

and in alexa console say:

> There was a problem with the requested skill's response

and in the device log say.

"descriptiveText": [
            "Request Identifier: amzn1.echo-api.request.f6d03bab-05b2-449f-877b-b58f8e28274b",
            "",
            "The skill returned an invalid response"
        ],

What could be causing this error?

thnks in advance

Comment: can you post your function here?